# Changed a service fabric collection name now getting error about two phase upgrades

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Two weeks ago I created a service fabric reliable dictionary with name "ABC" and Type "CBA".

A few days ago I changed the name of the type to "DEF", now when I deploy the application it fails to deploy (and also fails to rollback) with the exception:

> This commonly indicates that the user application is not backwards/forwards compatible. Common backwards/forwards compatibility bugs that lead to this error are adding a new type or changing an assembly name without two phase upgrade, or removing a type

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to undo the renaming action and tried to redeploy, then use proper two phase upgrade? If you are still in early stages you might take your data loss for granted and delete the whole service and redeploy again. Be sure to assess your update strategy  next time because these things are not easy to solve.

Comment: Well I have backups, so I'm just going to delete the service, roll back and restore the data. Thanks for the suggestion.